# How To Add And Update A Row To JTable From JTextField and Delete Row In Java

Tags: java, swing

I am recently new in this site. I have a problem to Add And Update in A Row To JTable From JTextField + Delete Row In Java will you please help me and give  Source Code

Comment: You will have to describe the problem.

Comment: *"give Source Code"* Hire someone. This is a Q&A site, not a code generation machine.

Comment: Read the `DefaultTableModel` API. There are methods for adding/deleting rows of data.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends of how you implemented your table, which columns are being used, what is being displayed...

Usually rows are added to and removed from the table model.
Here a very basic (incomplete) example using the DefaultTableModel:

```
private JTable table;
private DefaultTableModel model;

private void init() {
    model = new DefaultTableModel(...);
    table = new JTable(model);
    ...
}

private void addRow(String[] rowValues) {
    model.addRow(rowValues);
}

private void remRow(int rowIndex) {
    model.removeRow(rowIndex);
}
```

Normally it is recommended to create a TableModel specific for the data being displayed. See the [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) tutorial.